# cmd.Cmd object doesn't return any value

Tags: python, python-cmd

I am currently creating a command-based game using Python's `cmd` module.

At a certain point, my `cmd.Cmd` objects get nested. If I say that I am running the command prompt `A`, at a certain point a new prompt `B` is created inside `A`. I want to, when my `B` finishes, return a certain value to `A` again. All my trials have just ended up with the inner command prompts returning `None`. To try to understand this situation better I tried to simplify the question and just tried to get a return value from a `cmd.Cmd` object. This is what I have:

```
import cmd
class Test(cmd.Cmd):
    def __init__(self, value):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.value = value
    def do_bye(self, s):
        return True
    def postloop(self):
        print("Entered the postloop!")
        return self.value
```

And then at the shell I already tried:

```
a = Test("bla bla")
print(a.cmdloop())
# after the "bye" command it prints None

print(Test("bla bla").cmdloop())
# after the "bye" command it ALSO prints None

a = Test("safsfa").cmdloop()
print(a)
# Also prints None
```

I don't seem to be able to make the `cmd.Cmd` object return any value. How can one do that, or is it impossible for some reason I don't know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine `cmdloop()` in your subclass to return a particular value, after calling the superclass's version of `cmdloop()`:

```py
class Test(cmd.Cmd):
    # ...
    def cmdloop(self):
        cmd.Cmd.cmdloop(self)
        return self.value
```

Comment: Thanks. That does make sense, but I didn't think of it :P